# In mips can I use branch equal to jump to a certain row in my code?

Tags: mips

In mips can I use branch equal to jump to a certain row in my code? I know that we can jump to a label but can i provide the brach with a number and "jump" this number forward?

Comment: Sure, label or offset. Well, it depends on the assembler you use. Why would you want to though? You'd have to count the instructions, that's a bit annoying

Comment: You may do what @harold says or do an `addi` to the `$pc` register.

Comment: Thank you but I understood my mistake and fixed my code to avoid this. @babon

Comment: @babon: MIPS architecture does not have a programmer visible `$pc` register.

Comment: @markgz Yes, I am wrong. Thanks for pointing that out. Will keep that in mind.